# Contextual Filters

Tags: views

I have set up a Views Block for an events listing. I have set up a taxonomy vocabulary for Groups and have an extensive list under that. I have set up a Content Type for Events that has a field for the taxonomy list of events. What I need to do is when a visitor goes to that specific Group's page, there will be a listing of events specific to that group.

I have filtered the View by Content Type = Events. I can't wrap my head around how I will only show on each group page events under that group. Is this using Contextual Filters? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: Yes, I believe this is achievable using contextual filters.

To be more specific: I believe you'll be able to find a contextual filter "Content: Has taxonomy term ID". It's hard to be able to give you the information on what should go in here without knowing how the pages are constructed. But, for example, if you had pages that had the taxonomy term ID (for the Groups vocabulary) in the url, you could select:

Provide default value > Taxonomy term ID from URL. **You may have to use "Raw value from URL" and select 2 under path component because of how your urls are constructed**

There's also "Specify validation criteria".

Select "Taxonomy term" from that and you can limit it by vocabulary or even convert taxonomy term names into IDs.

To use a taxonomy term name from the url under "Filter value type" select "Term name" or "Term name converted to Term id" (note, it is much safer to use taxonomy term ids in the url as terms with the same name can not be distinguished). If you are using term names make sure you check "Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name filter values"

Hope that answers your question :)

Comment: I appreciate. I have set it up as a page View now, using /programs/%/events as the page view path. So, for example, if I go to programs/Program-1/events, I want all the events from the content type events with that taxonomy term selected (program 1) to show. However, nothing is showing.

Comment: I've updated the answer above in reference to the fact you are using term names in the url.